# deploy windows phone 8 App on Android or iOS or Other platforms using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, cross-platform

I have developed a Windows Phone 8 App, and I want the same to be deployed on iPhone(iOS) and Android platforms using PhoneGap. I have made my App in C# and XAML, unlike using HTML and JS. Can Anyone please guide me on the same on how to deploy my Win Phone 8 App on other platforms using PhoneGap.
Also is PhoneGap open source or do we need to subscribe for the same.
Also if any other tool is available to achieve the same without re-writing the whole code but using my code already written.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Anyone please any help on the same?.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to xamarin. With phonegap you will hav to rewrite your app in html, css and javascript

Comment: You will have to re-write app in phonegap (with HTML and JS) and then only you can deploy same to android and ios.